# How to shortcut nested clauses

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, optimization

How to shortcut or compact nested clauses like this?

```
if @user.name.present?
  if @user.username.present?
    name = @user.name + @user.username
  else
    name = @user.name
  end
else
  name = ""
end
```

I thought some way to concatenate both strings (like a = a + b)

Answer (score 0):

```
name= @user.try(:name) ? "#{@user.name}#{@user.try(:username)}" : ""
```

If you want to concat irrespective of absence of any of the attribute you could try below one.

```
name= "#{@user.try(:name)} #{@user.try(:username)}"
```

The `try` method returns value if present or nil value. Moreover you can nest deep with `try` without checking for its presence.

In ruby , use `Array` to do it.

```
[@user.name, @user.username].compact.join(" ")
```

here is the example

```
class User
    def name
        "john"
    end
    def username
        "doe"
    end
end
class NoUserName
    def name
        "john"
    end
    def username
        ""
    end
end
class NilUserName
    def name
        "john"
    end
    def username
        nil
    end
end
class NilUser
    def name
        nil
    end
    def username
        "Doe"
    end
end
class NoUser
    def name
        ""
    end
    def username
        "Doe"
    end
end
@user= User.new
puts [@user.name, @user.username].compact.join(" ").squeeze(' ').strip # "John Doe"
@user= NoUserName.new
puts [@user.name, @user.username].compact.join(" ").squeeze(' ').strip # "John"
@user= NilUserName.new
puts [@user.name, @user.username].compact.join(" ").squeeze(' ').strip # "John"
@user= NoUser.new
puts [@user.name, @user.username].compact.join(" ").squeeze(' ').strip # "Doe"
@user= NilUser.new
puts [@user.name, @user.username].compact.join(" ").squeeze(' ').strip # "Doe"
```

Comment: You should note that `try` is a Rails/ActiveSupport method which may not be applicable since the question is not tagged as a Rails question.

Comment: Sorry, but I can't accept this as accepted. You are doing different thinks than my code does. May be we need a "nested ternary"